# Passing data into Container View using Embed Segue

Tags: ios6, storyboard, uitableview, uidatepicker, uistoryboardsegue

So I've seen most of the tutorials (and am using the technique) to pass data from one view controller to the next when the segue is a push (in the prepareForSegue method). I can cast the `destinationViewController` to my custom class and push data into custom properties.

However, when I try to do this for an Embed Segue (the new one in iOS6 which allows Container Views to work), the destinationViewController doesn't seem to be right; it's just a UIViewController, not the custom class I have defined in the storyboard.

[image: Storyboard Example]

As you can see, I have my main table view with Start and End dates. I then have a subview, embedded using the Container View. This has a toolbar for command dates + a UIDatePicker.

My issue is that I need the main table view controller to have an event listener from the Date Picker (the `UIControlEventValueChanged` one, to update the labels). The parent controller can't see the date picker. Both View Controllers have custom classes implemented. The Date Picker controller class has the date picker as an IBOutlet object and the 3 date range buttons have selected methods which do change the date.

It seems my issue here is context between the two view controllers.

FYI: I need them separate so I can toggle the visibility of the date picker widget & toolbar.

#### UPDATE 1:

I have found a work around, which is on the prepare segue at parent level, pass a "self" reference to the child which has a property of the parent view controller type. This gives the child a proper reference to its parent, which I can then do the following with:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [[self datePicker] addTarget:[self graphSettingsViewController] action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

This works but feels "messy". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an Embed segue from a ViewController **Container** to a contained VC.

I was beginning to suspect that Apple has a bug or that in this case there might be another property on the segue (like maybe embeddedVC instead of destinationVC). But...

I finally found that somehow the the specific **source** view controller (in the storyboard) was changed to the stock UIViewController and that somehow messed things up. Not sure how that happened but once I fixed that, things began working again.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

**Passing data into Container View using Embed Segue**

```
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSString * segueName = segue.identifier;

    if ([segueName isEqualToString: @"toMenuCategory"]) {
        MenuCategoryVC * childViewController = (MenuCategoryVC *) [segue destinationViewController];
        childViewController.activityList = self.menuCategoryList;
        childViewController.setCategoryInfo= ^ (NSDictionary *dictCategoryInfo){

            NSLog(@"dictCategoryInfo = %@" ,  dictCategoryInfo);

        };



    }
}
```

**MenuCategoryVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MenuCategoryVC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray* activityList;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^setCategoryInfo)(NSDictionary *dictCategoryInfo);
```

**MenuCategoryVC.m**

```
// MARK: -
// MARK: - BUTTON NEXT ACTION

- (IBAction)actionNext:(id)sender {
    self.setCategoryInfo(categoriesData);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegation pattern. In prepareForSegue for the embed identifier set controller.delegate = self. Then in the child controller in the ibaction method call [self.delegate catgegoryChanged]